# Backing up an SQLite3 database on embed

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I am currently working on a C project that contains an SQLite3 database with WAL enabled. We have an HTTP web interface over which you shall be able to get an online backup of the database. Currently, the database file is reachable over HTTP, which is bad in many ways. My task now is to implement a new backup algorithm.

There is the SQLite-Online-Backup API which seems to be pretty nice. There, you open two database connections and *copy* one database to the other. Anyway, in my setup, I can't be sure that there is enough space to copy the entire database, since we may have a lot of statistics and multimedia files in it. For me, the best solution would be to open a SQLite connection that is directly connected to stdout, so that I could backup the database through CGI.

Anyway, I didn't find a way in the SQLite3 API to open a database connection on special files like stdout. What would be best practice to backup the database? How do you perform online backups of your SQLite3 databases?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have some special target interface for the backup, you can implement your custom VFS interface that does what you need. See the parameters for `sqlite3_open_v2()` where you can pass in the name of a VFS.
(see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html for Details about VFS and the OS interface used by SQLite)

Basically every `sqlite3_backup_step()` call will write some blocks of data, and you would need to transfer those to your target database in some way.

Comment: There is no special backup interface, I just want the database to be dumped to stdout (like it would when I do an HTTP download of the database file, but with access control and database integrity). Implementing my own VFS interface seems to be a little bit of an overkill. Would it be fine to set a write lock, do a WAL checkpoint and dump the database file afterwards?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use the sqlite3 command line tool (or the code from it), use the `.dump` command which writes to stdout and just read that data back in on the other side. Probably not the most efficient way though. (see https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html )

Comment: You can probably get it to work with something like 'pragma journal mode delete', get an exclusive lock and copy the database file and switch back to 'WAL' mode. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: I try to avoid shells from C code, I'm a little paranoid. Could I do as follows? Get exclusive lock -> sqlite3_wal_checkpoint() -> fd = fopen(database, "r") -> while(c = getc(fd) != EOF) putchar(c) -> fclose(fd) -> release lock -- or would that break anything?